# What do you call something that is not a substance in philosophy?

Tags: metaphysics

[Is the mind a substance in dual aspect monism?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/79210/is-the-mind-a-substance-in-dual-aspect-monism)

> In philosophy, "substance" is like "atom", which is the ultimate
> independent real existence not depending on other entities, is the
> unit of knowledge.

So let's say something is an existence that depends on some other entity. Let's say a banana in a game relies on a computer for its existence. What do you call such an object? A non-atom?

Comment: [Dependent object](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dependence-ontological/#AsymExisDepe).

Comment: ...and see [substance](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/substance/).

Comment: Per the bare term *substance* itself, it was usually paired with *attribute.* Then we had the question of intrinsic vs. extrinsic attributes, necessary vs. contingent attributes, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish the "x that is not a substance" from *nothing*? 

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experience of philosophy jargons, usually laypeople call it "phenomena", "thing", "stuff", "reflection", "illusion". People with science background usually call "composite", "matter". Some people with religion background call it "codependent arising", "dream". Some philosophy academic call "qualia", "emergence", etc... It sounds a little confusing, but that's the manifoldness of most human encounterings, and perhaps more importantly, it's a critical hint that seemingly dry philosophical thinking may help you not only understand yourself more, it may help you understand others more too...